# Python guessing game not working

Tags: python, random

I am making a python code that picks a random number and compares it to a guess made by the user.

```
import random
attempts=0
secret=random.randint(1,49)
print "welcome to my guessing game"
repeat
def repeat():
    guess=raw_input("I have thought of a number between 1 and 50. you have to try and guess it")
        if secret==guess:
            print "Well Done! you guessed it in "+attempts+" attempts"
        elif secret < guess:
            print "too high"
            guess=raw_input("have another go")
        elif secret > guess:
            print "too low"
            guess=raw_input("have another go")
    attempts += 1
while guess != secret and attempts>6:
    repeat()
```

but it is saying that repeat is not defined.

Comment: What is the line `repeat` supposed to be doing exactly? Note that this: 1. appears **before** you've actually defined the function; and 2. wouldn't do anything useful anyway.

Comment: When asking for help, please include the exact error message. You're calling repeat without parentheses about the function definition. As a side note, your condition at the bottom is most likely wrong. You probably mean ` while guess != secret and attempts<6:`

Comment: Delete 5th line with `repeat` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow the user to guess 7 times, then prints game over:
*this is for Python 2. for Python 3. use* `int(input(""))`

```
import random

secret = random.randint(1,49)
attempts = 0
for attempts in range(7):
    guess=input("I have thought of a number between 1 and 50. you have to try and guess it: ")
    if secret==guess:
        print "Well Done! you guessed it "
    elif secret < guess:
        print "too high"
        guess=input(" Enter to have another go")
    elif secret > guess:
        print "too low"
        guess=input("Enter to have another go")
    if attempts == 6:
        print "Game Over"
```

Answer (score 1):

The Program is not working because you can not run or call a function before it is created. Also you should call repeat by doing this "repeat()"

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted your code to the following which should work. You might want to read up on [Local and Global Variables](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php) as that's what was causing your main issue in your code.

```
import random

def repeat(secret, attempts):
    guess=raw_input("I have thought of a number between 1 and 50. you have to try and guess it")
    if secret==guess:
        print "Well Done! you guessed it in "+attempts+" attempts"
    elif secret < guess:
        print "too high"
        guess=raw_input("have another go")
    elif secret > guess:
        print "too low"
        guess=raw_input("have another go")
    attempts += 1
    while guess != secret and attempts < 6:
        repeat(secret, attempts)

attempts = 0
secret = random.randint(1,49)
print "welcome to my guessing game"
repeat(secret, attempts)
```

Comment: This will allow more than 6 attempts